# =FREQUENCY() function in Excel not outputting what I expect

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of years (total of 101 values, some duplicate) that I'm supposed to put into a graph to show the frequency that certain events occur (grouped into decades).

I used `=FREQUENCY(J2:J102,D7:D17)` and did the CTRL+SHIFT+RETURN when highlighting 12 blank cells adjacent to the bin limits. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, as there should be 6 values for <=1890, 8 for 1900, 4 for 1910 etc.

The stuff below is the information I used and the output I received:

```
Years

        1887
        1887
        1887
        1890
        1890
        1890
        1892
        1892
        1893
        1893
        1894
        1896
        1898
        1899
        1903
        1907
        1908
        1910
        1911
        1911
        1911
        1911
        1915
        1916
        ...
```

```
Bin Limit

        1890
        1900
        1910
        1920
        1930
        1940
        1950
        1960
        1970
        1980
        1990
        (additional row here for >1990)
```

```
The Bin Counts that get outputted

        7
        8
        0
        0
        1
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        85
```

Comment: I've entered the data from your example, but cannot reproduce the problem. I get the result exactly as expected. Perhaps you can check your data-type and formatting to see if the years are entered as whole numbers rather than an excel date value.

Comment: I, too, am getting the expected results from your posted data. Can you upload a copy of a workbook that reproduces the problem?

Comment: So I tried it again on my desktop computer, and it did it properly, but as soon as I opened the excel spreadsheet (that I was working with) it did the same thing. When I closed that specific spreadsheet, everything worked as normal. I have no idea what's wrong with it. Whether or not that would be of any use, but I just decided to use a completely separate spreadsheet and get rid of the other one

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but excel struggles with dates before 1900 as that's where the excel date number system starts. Anything before counts as a "negative date". You could try and look at your workbook options. In the Advanced tab there will be a setting "Use 1904 date system". Try checking (or unchecking) that option and see if it gets rid of your problem. This is workbook specific so it might have gotten checked (or unchecked) on accident.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that, as you didn´t fix your input matrix, when you shift it to get the remaining data, it is shifting the ranges too.

Try this:
`=FREQUENCY($J$2:$J$102,D7)` on the first cell and `=FREQUENCY($J$2:$J$102,D8)-SUM($D$7:D7)` on the second cell, so dragging on the remaining ones, you will get:

`=FREQUENCY($J$2:$J$102,D9)-SUM($D$7:D8)`

`=FREQUENCY($J$2:$J$102,D10)-SUM($D$7:D9)`

...

`=FREQUENCY($J$2:$J$102,D17)-SUM($D$7:D16)`

with the expected values. I can not give an elegant solution without the data... sorry

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since the OP "*did the CTRL+SHIFT+RETURN when highlighting 12 blank cells adjacent to the bin limits*", the cell references will not shift, even with the addressing mode he used.

Comment: I already tried on my system and the input matrix was shifted. Anyhow, it is not the best solution but I already tried it and it works.

Comment: You probably did not select all of the cells at the same time, and enter the formula as an array into all the cells simultaneously.  If you do that properly, it will not shift.

Comment: Hey, I just commented on my post about i working on my other computer but not working on whatever pc I had the spreadsheet open on (even if it was a different spreadsheet/file, as long as it was open)